# Jqvmap tooltips not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jqvmap

I'm using JQVMap (http://jqvmap.com/) world view to show a map of the world. When I hover over the countries, the tooltips are not showing. This is my JavaScript code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                                                    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
                                                        map: 'world_en',
                                                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                                        color: '#4D4D4D',
                                                        hoverColor: '#F05A23',
                                                        selectedColor: '#F05A23',
                                                        showTooltip: true,
                                                        enableZoom: false,
                                                        selectedRegions: ['US','CT'],
                                                        onRegionClick: function(event, code, region)
                                                        {
                                                            event.preventDefault();
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                });
```

Everything else works fine, just not the tooltips. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Also, the zoom controls are not showing. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @anoopchandran unfortunately no :(

Comment: I managed to fix this. I don't remember how, but I just copied a working version and tweaked it. I couldn't find the exact one I used for my project, but here is something similar. `http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/xbe5ke6q/`
I think you need to add world data(tooltip data) correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Didn't notice, that there was a CSS file in **dist** folder which I forgot to include. After adding styles, zoom controls and tooltips appeared.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, in my case the map was included in a css popup width z-index. The Z-index of the label from jqvmap was lower the from the popup so you have to format the label for a higher z-index:

```
.jqvmap-label {
z-index:999999;
```

}

Comment: Wow, thank you! This finally fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have linked the dist/jqvmap.min.css file into your project.